# Projection: filling 2 arrays at once

Tags: c#, linq

I thought I would be clever and write something like this code sample.  It also seemed like a clean and efficient way to fill an array without enumerating a second time.

```
int i = 0;
var tickers = new List<string>();
var resultTable = results.Select(result => new Company
{
      Ticker = tickers[i++] = result.CompanyTicker,
});
```

I don't really care for an alternative way to do this, because I can obviously accomplish this easily with a for loop. I'm more interested *why* this snippet doesn't work ie, `tickers.Count = 0` after the code runs, despite there being 100+ results.  Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this unexpected behavior?

Comment: This line looks weird: Ticker = tickers[i++] = result.CompanyTicker,

Comment: It **should** throw an exception somewhere...

Comment: @frenchie It assigns result.CompanyTicker to `tickers[i++]` and `Ticker`.

Comment: Question: how can you assign values directly to `tickers[n]` without first filling the list? Won't you get `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions?

Comment: @Chris you're right. It didnt occur to me for some reason and I got the exception after executing the query as per the answer.

Comment: If you want parliament, you can break your `Select` expression into a multi-line anonymous function instead and achieve same/comparable performance (although at 100+ results, even if you iterate several times I doubt you'll have performance issues). EDIT: Probably more readable too: `result => { tickers.Add(result.CompanyTicker); return new Company { Ticker = result.CompanyTicker; }; }` At least you don't need to parse several operations going on simultaneously.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Q in LINQ stands for Query which implies no side effects for _most_ developers.  Simply enumerating this when debugging will leave you in a state you may not want.

Comment: Honestly @parliament, unless you have a _measurable_ performance bottleneck with this, I'd still prefer to iterate on it twice: `var resultTable = results.Select(result => new Company { Ticker = result.CompanyTicker }).ToList(); var tickers = resultTable.Select(c => c.CompanyTicker).ToList();` To me this seems to more match the intent (albeit, I'm _assuming_ I know what your intent is), that you have a set of `Company` objects and some master list of their tickers.

Answer (score 8):

You need to iterate your query, for example use `.ToArray()` or `ToList()` at the end. Currently you just created a query, it **hasn't been executed** yet.

You may see: [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

*Plus, I believe your code should throw an exception, for `IndexOutOfRange`, since your List doesn't have any items.*

Answer (score 2):

This is due to LINQ's lazy execution. When the query gets executed (i.e. when you iterate over it), the list should have your results. An easy way to do this is to use `ToArray`or`ToList`.

Comment: Even after you trigger execution this code will fail due to an IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1):

Linq should ideally not have side affects.

I don't see what would prevent this from being a two step process:

```
var tickers = results.Select(r => r.CompanyTicker).ToList();

var resultTable = tickers.Select(t => new Company { Ticker = t }).ToList();
```